# Erro ao solicitar a request PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-request

Galera, estou com um problema aqui!!!
Estou segmentando os verbos http aqui no thunder client, quando eu envio uma request de GET e de POST, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando é uma request de PUT dá o seguinte erro:
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

A questão é que minha variavel não é uma constante, mas uma let:

```
let users = [
{id: 1, nome: 'paula', idade: 23},
{id: 2, nome: 'fabio', idade: 40}
];
export {users};
```

users está em um outro arquivo, então eu estou usando o import e export

```
//arquivo principal:
import { users } from "./users.js";
```

Quando eu dou a request PUT ele dá o erro que mencionei, mas curiosamente se users estiver no arquivo principal, e não separado, a request PUT funciona perfeitamente.
Não sei mais o que fazer, me ajudem!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: acho que seu erro não na parte do código acima, provavelmente é aonde está usando o put.. pode postar o trecho completo??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Os imports são read-only. Se quiseres modificar um valor de um import tens de usar uma função.

```
let users = [
{id: 1, nome: 'paula', idade: 23},
{id: 2, nome: 'fabio', idade: 40}
];

function setUsers(u) {
    users = u;
}

export {users, setUsers};
```